# DropDownLists events firing but now showing being wrapped on an UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Just as I said in the title, I've a few DropDownLists inside of an UpdatePanel, which events changes each other's content.
I have these Dropdowns inside this UpdatePanel because I need them to not Postback or reload my page, because I also have a FileUpload control which I don't want to lose its selected item after changing the SelectedItem of any of the dropdowns.

I put a breakpoint in the OnSelectedIndexChanged events of the dropdowns and it's firing and doing all the code behind correctly, but doesn't show the charged dropdowns correctly.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ID="updatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" CssClass="combo" style="width: 100px;"AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 175px;" ID="ddl2" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged" CssClass="combo"> </asp:DropDownList>  
    <asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server" Size="70" style="width:auto;" />
  </ContentTemplate>    
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm open to suggestions on how to do this in another way.

Comment: You are using legacy technique. You can use javascript or jqery instead. Some example of cascading dropdown you can easily find on internet. like one which used web-service. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vemuhemanth/cascading-dropdown-in-Asp-Net-using-jquery/

Comment: I thought on using JS or jQuery but I wanted to see if it was possible without it

Comment: Definitely it is possible. You need to check for any javascript error on your console. Also define **but doesn't show the charged dropdowns correctly.** Put the code of dropdown change in your question.